# resample time series data pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file divided every 10 minutes that informs me of the number of passengers per line, but I have a gap from 1 pm to 4:50 it does not have a registration, how can I fill it with the number of passengers 0

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIcNh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new dataframe with the dates and number of passengers you want by using [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range) to create the dates:

```
>>> start_date = pd.to_datetime("2021-11-08 00:50:00.000")
>>> end_date = pd.to_datetime("2021-11-08 05:00:00.000")
```

The keyword argument `inclusive` is available from 1.4.0 and forward. For previous versions, you'll have to add the 10 minutes to `start_date` and subtract the same time amount to `end_date`, since both values would be included by default in your date range:

```
>>> target_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq="10min", inclusive="neither")
```

Now you can create your dataframe with the new rows and use `.concat` to include your original data:

```
>>> new_rows_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": target_date_range,
})
>>> new_rows_df["passengers"] = 0
>>> new_rows_df.head()
                 date  passengers
0 2021-11-08 01:00:00           0
1 2021-11-08 01:10:00           0
2 2021-11-08 01:20:00           0
3 2021-11-08 01:30:00           0
4 2021-11-08 01:40:00           0

>>> df = pd.concat([df, new_rows_df])
```